# AngularJs Filter array objects with property file extension

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

I have the following array of attachment object with the properties as

```
{
  "attachment": {
    "size":789917,
    "thumb":false,
    "dateUploaded":1495467121848,
    "name":"Alonso+2007.obj",
    "id":2828
  },
  "id":2828
}
```

Need to filter the list having the file with extension ".obj" EX: files with name "filename.obj" should only be returned. Tried the following code

```
    <div ng-repeat="attachment in contribution.attachments | filter:{name:'Alonso+2007.obj'}">
```

But did not get any result. Not sure how to extract the properties with extension. tried with split() and indexof() but didnt not get the result.

Comment: you have to create filter method and apply that in view file wth `filter:filtermethod`

Comment: I tried the following method just to check if filter works.                            
        var temp = $filter("filter")(attachment, { name: "Alonso+2007.obj" });
        console.log("After filter", temp);

Comment: Have u checked double quotes...it should be at the end   <div ng-repeat="attachment in contribution.attachments | filter:{name:'Alonso+2007.obj'}">

Comment: @TKHN : Oops the quotes were correct, but that didnt work. Not sure on how to extract the .obj extention

Comment: Is each `attachment` object in the repeater scope the `attachment` property in your top example or is it the complete example? If the latter, you probably need `filter: {attachment: {name: '.obj' } }`

Comment: @Phil 5 : Thanks yes its working now. It was in the repeater scope.